# Exponentiation of big numbers with Euler Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I need to compute $5^{12241} \pmod{13}$ and as suggestion I have that I should use the Euler's theorem.

The latter states that whether $a$ is relatively prime to $n$ then $a^{\phi(n)}=1\pmod{n}$.

But how this consideration can be used to compute the exponentiation of big numbers?

Comment: In this case, you ought to write $12241=k\cdot\phi(13)+r$, where $0\le r<\phi(13)$ and use Euler's theorem. The exact value of $k$ does not really matter.

Comment: can you elaborate more? why it holds?

Comment: Well, the point is that $\phi(n)<n$, so it helps reducing the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi(13)=12$, the suggestion amounts to making use of the fact that $5^{12} = 1$ mod $13$. So for example
$$5^{12241} = 5^{12000} \times 5^{240} \times 5^1 = (5^{12})^{1000} \times (5^{12})^{20} \times 5^1 = 1^{1000} \times 1^{20} \times 5 = 5 \,\,\text{mod $13$}
$$

Comment: And $5^{12} = 1$ $mod 13$ in view of the Fermat Little Theorem. this is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

We don't need Fermat's Little Theorem or Totient theorem here

As $5^2\equiv-1\pmod{13},5^4\equiv1$

and $12241\equiv1\pmod4\implies5^{12241}\equiv5^1\pmod{13}$